Bloqueo o Errores SQL (Aplicacion WPF .NET Framework 4,8) C#
Como dice en el título estoy desarrollando una aplicacion de escritorio en WPF y en .NET Framework 4.8.(Todo con Visual Studio 2022)
Estoy utilizando SQL EXPRESS de motor de BD con la instalacion basica.
Soy programador de PLC y soy nuevo en este tipo de desarrollos y entornos informáticos aunque me defiendo.
Mi aplicación parte de un Login que autentica contra la BD y te permite acceder. Una vez dentro tengo una serie de ventanas, 3 de ellas con consultas a BD.
Una genera informes de proceso, otra edita recetas y la ultima saca 7 gráficos con información estática recogida de la BD.(Paquete Nuget LiveCharts).
De un tiempo a esta parte empece a recibir fallos de bloqueo y errores de SQL 26 o 40.
Dado que tanto la autenticación como la string de conexión son correctas (asi como las configuraciones de memoria, usuarios etc..de SQL server), entiendo que algo me esta saturando el acceso a la BD. Tras unos minutos sin poder ni loguear, ya que el acceso a la BD se me interrumpe, luego continua funcionando normal hasta que vuelve a fallar.
Entiendo que las consultas pueden no estar optimizadas(aunque son bastante sencillas) y la carga de gráficos(Que es donde creo esta el problema) puede no hacerse de  la manera mas eficaz, ya que llamo a los métodos, genero las series para los charts y los cargo.
Las consultas las hago con using con lo que entiendo que es correcto a la hora de gestionar la conexion a la DB.
Probé a cambiar los métodos a async pero me da mas problemas que soluciones a la hora de manejar las conexiones. He decidido abrir esta pregunta porque he agotado todo lo que se me ha ocurrido para probar.
Gracias a todo el que pueda/quiera ayudar.
Dejo un ejemplo de un método de carga de 2 gráficos.
private void UpdatePieCharts(int retortId)
{
try
{
    string pieChartQuery = @"
SELECT 
    PrcStatus,
    COUNT(DISTINCT PrcId) AS ProcessCount,
    SUM(PrcTotalTime) AS TotalTimeMinutes
FROM 
    Process
WHERE 
    PrcRetortId = @RetortId
GROUP BY 
    PrcStatus;";

    int totalProcesses = 0; 

    
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pieChartQuery, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RetortId", retortId);
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dataTable);

                if (dataTable.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MyPieChart.Series = new SeriesCollection();
                    MyPieChart2.Series = new SeriesCollection();
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay datos disponibles para este Retort.", 
                    "Información", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    TotalTimeMachine.Content = "";
                    return;
                }

                totalProcesses = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => row.Field<int> 
                ("ProcessCount"));
                var completedCount = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => 
               row.Field<int>("PrcStatus") == 1).Sum(row => row.Field<int> 
                 ("ProcessCount"));
                var abortedCount = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int> 
               ("PrcStatus") == 2).Sum(row => row.Field<int>("ProcessCount"));

                double completedPercentage = totalProcesses == 0 ? 0 : 
                (double)completedCount / totalProcesses * 100;
                double abortedPercentage = totalProcesses == 0 ? 0 : 
                (double)abortedCount / totalProcesses * 100;

                
                var pieSeries1 = new PieSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { completedPercentage },
                    Title = "Completado",
                    Fill = Brushes.LimeGreen
                };

                var pieSeries2 = new PieSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { abortedPercentage },
                    Title = "Abortado",
                    Fill = Brushes.IndianRed
                };

                MyPieChart.Series = new SeriesCollection { pieSeries1, pieSeries2 };

                var totalTimeMinutes = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => 
                row.Field<int>("TotalTimeMinutes"));
                double totalHoursWorked = totalTimeMinutes / 60.0;
                TotalTimeMachine.Content = $"{totalHoursWorked:F2} horas";
            }
        }

        
        string allProcessesQuery = @"
    SELECT 
        COUNT(DISTINCT PrcId) AS ProcessCount
    FROM 
        Process;";

        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(allProcessesQuery, conn))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2))
            {
                DataTable allProcessesData = new DataTable();
                adapter2.Fill(allProcessesData);

                if (allProcessesData.Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    MyPieChart2.Series = new SeriesCollection();
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay datos disponibles para ninguna Retort.", 
                    "Información", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    return;
                }

                var totalAllProcesses = allProcessesData.AsEnumerable().Sum(row => 
                row.Field<int>("ProcessCount"));
                double currentMachinePercentage = totalAllProcesses == 0 ? 0 : 
                (double)totalProcesses / totalAllProcesses * 100;

                var pieSeriesCurrentMachine = new PieSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { currentMachinePercentage },
                    Title = $"Procesos de {retortId}",
                    Fill = Brushes.CornflowerBlue
                };

                var pieSeriesOtherMachines = new PieSeries
                {
                    Values = new ChartValues<double> { 100 - currentMachinePercentage },
                    Title = "Otras Maquinas",
                    Fill = Brushes.DarkGray
                };

                MyPieChart2.Series = new SeriesCollection { pieSeriesCurrentMachine, 
               pieSeriesOtherMachines };
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Error al obtener datos: {ex.Message}", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
}

}

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! En tu codigo no se ve nada malo. Todo lo que te pasa puede deberse a otras cosas, inclusive a los controles que usas para desplegar los graficos. Probaste con un profiler, o hacer otra aplicacion mas basica a ver si te pasa lo mismo, para descartar que no sea un problema de la pc?

Ya he probado un profiler pero tampoco se que datos debo mirar exactamente.
Por lo que veo no llega a pasar del 30 en el trace.
